# Eloququent: relationship from relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Have three tables / models:

Clients:

`id - client`

Brands:

`id - brand`

BrandModels:

`id - model - brand_id`

BrandModelClients:

`id - brandmodel_id - client_id`

I would like to get a "group by" clients list based on the **brands** in the cleanest way. Right now, I'm doing it in a dirty way.

So the point is that if I have a client who has three different cars of the same brand, get just one client element.

Comment: plz post what u tried. and the model code

Comment: $brand_model_clients = BrandModelClients::with(['brand', 'brands_models'])->get()->groupBy('brands_model_id');

Answer (score 0):

I not getting a proper structure of your database, but you should use eloquent relation like below: for more read [eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)

```
Class Brand extends Model{

    public function models(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\BrandModel', 'brand_id');
    }
}


Class BrandModel extends Model{

    public function clients(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\BrandModelClient', 'brandmodel_id');
    }
}

Class BrandModelClient extends Model{

    public function client(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client', 'client_id');
    }
}

$brands = Brand::with('models.clients.client')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with two queries this way:

//One to get all models

`$models_list = BrandModel::whereIn('brand_id', $list_fav_brands)->get()->pluck('id','model');`

//Second to get the clients

`$client_list = BrandModelsClient::whereIn('brands_model_id', $models_list)->with('client')->get()->pluck('client.id','client.name');`